# Multiple query result in a single result json

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, metamug

Below is my request tag.

```
 <Request method="GET" >
   <Query>
     select colA as "a", colB as "b", colC "c"
     from tableX
   </Query>

   <Query>
     select colP as "a", colQ as "b"
     from tableY
   </Query>
 </Request>
```

**Output**

```
[
  [{"a":40,"b":22,"c":63},{"a":28,"b":72,"c":91}],
  [{"a":53,"b":12},{"a":35,"b":74},{"a":95,"b":84},{"a":15,"b":60}]
]
```

Now the app developer is requesting to have all the json data in a single array. So that he can map to objects in a single list.

But metamug gives 2 different arrays in the main array, when two separate queries are used in the request tag.

Their [documentation](https://metamug.com/docs/resource-file.php) does not mention how to achieve this. I'm using postgres for the database.

Thanks.

Comment: why not send a single query instead of 2? something like `<Query>select x.colA as "a", x.colB as "b", colC "c", y.colP as "p", y.colQ as "q" from tableX x, tableY y</Query>`

Comment: This will cross join the results. I will have 2x4 = 8 records. I think that's not the right. I want to have 6 records in a single array. Currently I'm getting 2,4 in two arrays

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Union` to join the two results, but then in the 2nd query, you'll have to add one more *dummy* column so that number of columns match and also their datatypes.
(Please go through [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/typeconv-union-case.html) to learn more on what necessary type measures to take before using `UNION`.)
So you can write your resource file this way.

```
<Request method="GET" >
   <Query>
     (select colA as "a", colB as "b", colC "c"
     from tableX)
     UNION
     (select colP as "a", colQ as "b", 'dummy' as "c"
     from tableY)
   </Query>
 </Request>
```

See I added an extra column `c` with default text **'dummy'**, Also I assumed that the column type of `c` of the first query is `text`, if that is not the case then make appropriate changes.